# NX Angular Monorepo on AZURE: How to decouple an App

Tags: angular, angular-cli, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have a number of Angular libraries and apps within a NX monorepo. I would like to be able to decouple (correct term?) one specific app so I can make it available for other developers, outside/3rd party, to use without exposing the complete monorepo to them.

Is there a way to do this?